# How to use the 'date' command to display week number of the year?

Tags: command-line, string, text-formatting, system-information

I want the UNIX `date` to output:

```
So this is week 35 of 2016.
```

Here, of course, 35 and 2016 are outputs of the date command. I have tried the following:

```
date +%U
```

This printed out the current week number. But I have to wrap it inside the specific text I want to display. I tried:

```
date "So this is week: %U"
date "It is currently: "+ "%U"
```

Both gave me an error. How can I make the `date` command display the week number to me in the specific format that I desire?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The entire format string is to be preceded by the `+`:

```
$ date +"So this is week: %U"
So this is week: 19
$ date +"So this is week: %U of %Y"
So this is week: 19 of 2016
```

Comment: Thank you. How to add the 'year' after the week '19' part though? e.g. `So this is week 35 of 2016.`

Comment: Add a `of %Y` after the `%U` in the string.

Answer (score 11):

There are two kinds of week:

- Monday as first day
- Sunday as first day

So its not all the same when you are in different day of a week(CentOS7):

```bsh
[root@vm01.dev.cd:~]# date
Mon Aug 26 18:02:47 CST 2019

[root@vm01.dev.cd:~]# date +%U
34

[root@vm01.dev.cd:~]# date +%V
35
```

```bsh
date --help
  %U   week number of year, with Sunday as first day of week (00..53)  
  %V   ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53)
```

Answer (score 8):

There are actually 3 kind of week number in year for the date command :

- %U     week number of year, with Sunday as first day of week (00..53)
- %W     week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)
- %V     ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add the **command substitution** using backquotes (``) like this:

```
echo "So this is week `date +%V` of `date +%Y`."
```

They are evaluated *before* the expression is processed further and often come in handy, if a command doesn't provide that feature.
Nevertheless - since `date` is capable of it, [murus' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282610/369063) seems to be best practice in that case.

Answer (score 1):

don't mess calendar week/year with ISO week/ISO year!
e.g. the solution

```
echo "So this is week `date +%V` of `date +%Y`."
```

**is not correct**!, because for example for 1.1.2023 it will return nonsence:

```
> date -d "2023/01/01" +"%F is week %V year %Y"
2023-01-01 is week 52 year 2023
```

only use pairs +%V +%G for ISO calendar, or +%W/%U +%Y for normal calendar:

```
> date -d "2023/01/01" +"%F is week %V year %G"
2023-01-01 is week 52 year 2022
> date -d "2023/01/01" +"%F is week %W year %Y"
2023-01-01 is week 00 year 2023
```

more info on Wiki: [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)